# Custom events dispatch in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collision-detection, backbone-events

I want to write a simple JavaScript animation that makes some balls move inside a canvas. I want to detect collisions with custom events handled with Backbone.js instead of having a nested *for* loop that checks for collisions between each pair of balls.

```
var j;
for (j = 0; j < N_BALLS; j++) {
    ball_center = new Point(..., ...);
    ball_shape = new Circle(ball_center, ball_radius);
    ball_velocity = ...;
    ball_ID = j;
    balls[j] = new Ball(ball_shape, ball_velocity, ball_ID);
    _.extend(balls[j], Backbone.Events);
    balls[j].on("imhere", balls[j].event_handler);
}

function animate() {
    if (!paused) {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var j;
        for (j = 0; j < N_BALLS; j++){
            balls[j].updatePosition();
            balls[j].trigger("imhere", balls[j].shape, balls[j].ID);
        }
        for (j = 0; j < N_BALLS; j++)
           balls[j].draw(context, '#0000ff');
        window.requestNextAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
}
```

The event_handler is a member method of each Ball object

```
Ball.prototype.event_handler = function(shape, ID) {
    console.log("ball " + this.ID + " caught message from ball " + ID);
};
```

I would expect that sometimes a ball catches one message from another one, but this is NEVER the case.

I would like to arrange things in such a way where the event handler can:

- forward the event when `this.ID == ID`
- stop event propagation if `this.ID != ID`

Answer (score 1):

## Backbone events

`this.ID` is probably undefined because [Backbone `.on()` needs the context as the last param](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13132970/1218980) unless you're already binding the context to the function elsewhere manually.

---

You're also registering the event on the Ball itself, and triggering on the ball as well.

Events aren't global within Backbone, you need to create a global event channel yourself or use a plugin. Look for *event bus*, or *event aggregator*, etc.

A quick example could be as simple as:

```
var GlobalEvents = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

Backbone itself is a an object that extends the `Backbone.Events` functionality, but it's best to create a local event channel for your use-case.

---

Speaking of using the `Backbone.Events` object, you're extending each instances of a `Ball` when you really should be extending the `Ball` prototype once.

```
_.extend(Ball.prototype, Backbone.Events);
```

---

**You should [favor `listenTo` over `on`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16823746/1218980).**

When destroying a ball, you could call `ball.stopListening()` and you would avoid memory leaks. It would also solve the [context](https://dmitripavlutin.com/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/) problem within the `event_handler` callback.

So, with a global event aggregator:

```
balls[j].listenTo(GlobalEvents, "imhere", balls[j].event_handler);
```

---

Backbone events are not DOM events and they're not bubbling up and down, so there's no `stopPropagation` or `preventDefault`. In the background, it's just vanilla JS for Backbone.

---

## Collision detection

Now that we've covered the events part, let me just say that it's not the best solution for collision detection.

It's exactly the same as if you would call a `isCollindingWith(ball)` function on every other ball when updating the position. That's what's going on with the events, but with the loops hidden in the events implementation.

Tackling an optimized collision detection algorithm in this answer would be too broad, so I'll just link to this great article on [2D collision detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection).

The interesting part is at the end, where they talk about *spacial data structures* like *Quad Trees, R-Trees or Spacial Hashmaps.*